# Accessing dependencies of one rule from another

Tags: function, makefile, gnu-make

We are trying to have our makefile be self-documenting and want to be able to do something like

```
make targets
```

and have it list the targets that the user might want to use.  As part of this, we would like to display all of the `.PHONY` targets.  Is there a way to get the prerequisites of one target (`.PHONY` in particular) from another rule?

I am hoping to be able to do something like

```
.PHONY: clean build

targets:
   @echo $(prerequisites .PHONY)
```

and then run it as

```
$ make targets
clean build
```

We are using GNU make but would prefer a solution that works with other make if possible.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible in GNU make, and certainly not in generic make.  You can keep the list if targets in a variable, then use the variable twice:

```
PHONY = clean build

.PHONY: $(PHONY)

targets:
        @echo $(PHONY)
```

That's about it.